# Call anonymous function without commas between input variables

Tags: matlab, function

I have an anonymous function with 10 variables
now I want to evaluate it with data in a p=1x10 matrix like this:

```
answer=func(p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7),p(8),p(9),p(10))
```

i don't want to use this, i need something like:

```
answer=func(p(:))
```

but it generates error
can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark on the left) to indicate the system that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have some basic misunderstandings using [**anonymous functions and its syntax**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

For what I think you want to do, you basically have three options:

### Option 1

Define the function with **10 input parameters** and provide **10 input values** - ***OR*** expand an input array as [**comma separated list**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) using `{:}` which requires an intermediate `num2cell` step:

```
func1 = @(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j
p = num2cell(p)
answer = func1(p{:})
```

### Option 2

Define the function with **1 input parameters** using an array with **10 values** and provide this array:

```
func2 = @(p) p(1) + p(2) + p(3) + p(4) + p(5) + p(6) + p(7) + p(8) + p(9) + p(10)
answer = func2(p)
```

### Option 3

The last option to use **`varargin`** is really case dependent and could look like:

```
func3 = @(varargin) [varargin{:}]
p = num2cell(p)
answer = func3(p{:})
```

Comment: But `p` is not a cell array originally. You need `num2cell` first: `pc = num2cell(p); answer = func1(pc{:})`

Comment: @LuisMendo sure, gracias por el consejo ;) fixed!

Comment: @thewaywewalk Hahaha. ¡De nada! And +1 now

Comment: Or, alternatively, for a given fixed function `func` which OP has, you could define a front-end `func_front=@(p) func(p(1),p(2),...,p(10))`. At least this is how I interpret the question.